# LCDHype and Noritake GU128x64-800

Tags: driver, lcd, vfd

I use LCDHype with various types of LCD that I have.
But I can´t use it properly with a GU128x64-800.
The driver initialises the display and I can see messages using the driver designed for the GU192x16-800.
My display only shows 16 px in vertical in graphical mode and in text mode.

I'm wondering if it's possible to modify the driver for a 128 x 64 resolution in order to use the screen properly?

Tweaking the settings in the LCD configuration doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: You might try to find LcdStudio v2.1 from the internet (the official site is dead for years). I used to use LcdStudio for my Noritake 3900 back in the day.

Comment: @UNOPARATOR i have installed the lcdstudio in a laptop, but the program not contain the driver for the display, the 3000 series, and the 800 series are not the same. I know that the creator  of the lcdhype (@ViRuSTriNiTy) it is stack user maybe he can help, if read the quesion.

Comment: @JakeDoe I’m not the creator if the driver, it was provided by a forum user in the year 2006. I could retrieve the source code after some digging from my older HDDs. Unfortunately the driver is pretty much hard-coded to 192x16. It would require an greater effort to updated the driver so that it supports your resolution and the next hurdle is that is was written in C++ and for the old driver interface.

As for myself, i’m pretty much not invested into the whole LCD story anymore and i can barely remember things happening 10 years ago.

Is anyone having the coding skills to take the task?

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy Hi, thanks for your answer, i have some research in the datasheets of both displays and i see minor differences between them. The commands are the same, and the timings are the same (that´s the reason why can see the messages in the display), the only difference i can see, resides in the cgram.

Comment: (cont),  in the 800 the cgram is composed of 16384
bits arranged as (128 x 64 bits) x 2 and the access is operated by 8 bit vertical data, and in the 192x16 the cgram is composed of 16384
bits arranged as (256 x 32 bits) x 2 and same 8 bit in vertical data. In the 800 X address goes to 00H to 7FH, and the Y address goes to 0H to FH. The 192x16 the X address goes to 00H to FFH, and the Y address goes to 0H to 7H. That´s the difference i can see from the datasheets. Please can you post the source code?. Thanks for all

Comment: @JakeDoe I couldn't find a datasheet for GU192x16-800. But please drop me a message via e-mail to continue the discussion. You should have my e-mail address already. Lengthily discussions via comments are not very well received on SO. Surely the result can be posted here then.